# How would creating run time applications for CosmOS based operating systems work

Tags: c#, cosmos

I'm building a project with CosmOS and am having trouble with how I would go about making a method for user-based apps, my first instinct making a language specific to the OS, is there a method for loading programs at run time that I've just missed?

Answer (score 0):

You would most likley need to create everything from scratch. I recommend using bytecode for now because cosmos doesn't allow you to directly run asm code. Here is an example of running bytecode:

```cs
for (int I = 0; I < Bytes.Length; I++)
{
    switch (Bytes[I]
    {
        case 0x0: // close app
               return;
    }
}
```